# Infinite loop using react Drizzle component

Tags: erc-721, nft, react, drizzle, api-design

**This might be the best place to ask this.**

I'm having an **infinite loop** issue when fetching my NFT's json **URI**.
My main issue was being able to display my NFT's name on the screen but now i'm getting an infinite loop. My function that does the fetching keeps getting called.

**What I've tried:**

- useEffect [] *WITH THE ARRAY THING*
- Moving the API call function outside of the components scoop
- UseCallback
- Async

[Link to my Stack overflow question that helped me display metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68733442/4115530)

Could the Drizzle component be getting re-render ? And causing an infinite loop?

**What's being rendered on the Browser.**

```
export default ({ drizzle, drizzleState }) => { 
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <ContractData
        drizzle={drizzle}
        drizzleState={drizzleState}
        contract="MyContract"
        method="totalSupply"
        labels="length"
        render={(totalSupply) => {
          const emptyArray = [];
          const arrayLength = Number(totalSupply);
          for(let i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){ emptyArray.push('') }
          if(emptyArray.length === 0) {
            return (
              <Jumbotron className="no-artwork">
                Nothing to see.
              </Jumbotron>
            )
          }
          return (
              <div className="collection-container">
                  {emptyArray.map(( _, index) => {
                    return (
                      <ContractData
                        key={index}
                        drizzle={drizzle}
                        drizzleState={drizzleState}
                        contract="MyContract"
                        method="tokenByIndex"
                        methodArgs={[arrayLength - 1 - index]}
                        render={(tokenId) => (
                          <>
                            <DisplayImage tokenId={tokenId} drizzle={drizzle} drizzleState={drizzleState} />
                          </>
                        )}
                      />
                    )}
                  )}
              </div>
            );
        }}
      />
  <div/>
 )};
```

**DisplayImage component** outside of export and what is rendering the images and metadata.

```
const DisplayImage = (NftData) => {
  const [nftMetadata ,setNftMetadata] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setNftMetadata(GetURI(NftData))
  }, [GetURI,NftData]);
  
  return (
    <div>

      <ContractData
        drizzle={NftData.drizzle}
        drizzleState={NftData.drizzleState}
        contract="MyContract"
        method="CID"
        methodArgs={[NftData.tokenId]}
        render={(cid) =>  {
            return(
              <div className="token-container">
                <h2>{nftMetadata.name}</h2>
                <img className="artwork" width="250px" src={`https://ipfs.fleek.co/ipfs/${cid}`} />
              </div>
              )
      
          }}
      />

    </div>
  );

}
```

**Function fetching URI**

I only want this to be called once per NFT , but something is causing an infinite loop. Am I missing something with **useEffect** or could it really be **Drizzle**?

```
const GetURI = async (data) => {
  
  const nftURI = await data.drizzle.contracts.MyContract.methods.tokenURI(data.tokenId).call()
  

  await fetch(nftURI , {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data || '';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log(err);
  });
  
};
```

I'm brainstorming a way to do useEffect inside export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer if anyone needs this in the future.

```
const DisplayImage = (data) => {

  const [nftMetadata, setNftMetadata] = useState();

  const GetURI = async (data) => {
     const nftURI = await data.drizzle.contracts.Contract.methods.tokenURI(data.tokenId).call()

      await fetch(nftURI , {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        })
        .then(data => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          return setNftMetadata(data || []);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return console.log(err);
      });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    GetURI(data);
  }, [data.tokenId])   
  
  return (
    <div className="token-container">

     <h2>{nftMetadata.name}</h2>
     <img className="artwork" width="450px" src={`https://ipfs:/whatever/${nftMetadata.image}`} />

    </div>
  );

};
```

```
return (
 <div>

  {array.map(index) => {

   // Some Other Code That returns a TokenID //

   <>
    <DisplayImage address={drizzle.contractList[0].address} tokenId={tokenId} drizzle={drizzle} drizzleState={drizzleState}/>
   </>
 
 </div>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect(...)` function sets state, which will cause the component to be re-rendered, calling the function again, which will set state and so on...

To fix this, either only set the state if the value from `GetURI(...)` is different to `nftMetadata` or convert the component to a class and do this in `componentDidMount()`.